# Need to convert from a JSON file to DDL statement using Python 3x

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, ddl

I have a task to generate DDL statement using Python from a JSON file.

Here's the JSON code,

```
{
    "root": {
        "columns": [
       {
        "src_name": "",
        "target_name": "id",
        "target_type": {
          "datatype": "int",
          "width": 14
       },
        "target_options": {
          "nullable": false,
          "autoincrement": true
        }
      },
      {
        "src_name": "source primary key",
        "target_name": "src_pkey",
        "target_type": {
          "datatype": "varchar",
          "width": 250
       },
        "target_options": {
          "nullable": false           
        }
      },
      {
        "src_name": "vendor name",
        "target_name": "vendor_name",
        "target_type": {
          "datatype": "varchar",
          "width": 250
       },
        "target_options": {
          "nullable": false           
        }
      },
       {
        "src_name": "create date",
        "target_name": "create_dt",
        "target_type": {
         "datatype": "timestamp",
          "fractional": 0
        },
        "target_options": {
          "nullable": false,
          "default": "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"
        }
      },
      {
        "src_name": "create date",
        "target_name": "create_dt",
        "target_type": {
         "datatype": "timestamp",
          "fractional": 0
        },
        "target_options": {
          "nullable": false,
          "default": "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"
        }
      }
     ],
    "target_primaryKey": {
      "columns": [
        {
          "column": "id"
        }
      ]
    },
    "target_uniqueKeys": [
      {
        "columns": [
          {
            "column": "vendor_name"
          }
        ],
        "name": "unq_name"
      }
    ],
    "target_options": {
      "comment": "All system users",
      "engine": "MyISAM"
    }
   }
}
```

I need to generate a CREATE TABLE statement for the JSON file.

The sample SQL should be like,

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME (
    id int(14) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    src_pkey varchar(250) NOT NULL,
    vendor_name varchar(250) NOT NULL,
    create_dt timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

I've tried other references, e.g., [Creating a Data Structure from JSON Using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48604563/creating-a-data-structure-from-json-using-python)

But, not able to understand.

PS: I've just started learning Python, so, I don't have much knowledge in this language.

Comment: check this: https://pypi.org/project/ddlgenerator/

Comment: Your json makes little sense. Either clarify what goes where and what kind of table you expect to get or read up on python dictionaries and json format and try again.

Comment: @IcedLance I've updated the details what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @ncica thanks for the reference. Tried that and got the below block of codes,

  File "c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\lib\site-packages\ddlgenerator\reshape.py", line 289, in unnest_children
    for (key, val) in row.items():
RuntimeError: OrderedDict mutated during iteration