# Python with JSON Create Table SQL

Tags: python, json

I have 2 list

```
c_name = ['departmentid', 'name', 'groupname', 'modifieddate']
d_type =['integer', 'character varying', 'character varying', 'timestamp without time zone']
```

And I would like to create a SQL query for creating a tables

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE(
  'departmentid' 'integer',
  'name' 'character varying',
  'groupname' 'character varying',
  'modifieddate' 'timestamp without time zone'
);
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is get the SQL command as text, you can do this with a combination of string concatenation (or formatting) and for loops.

If you want to "connect" to a database and execute the queries, read up on "database connectors" for the relevant database (such as MySQL, SQLite, SQLPlus etc).

---

**Edit**

Here's one way to do it. I don't want to just give you an answer without an explanation, but I hope this is self explanatory. Feel free to ask anything confusing.

```py
c_name = ['departmentid', 'name', 'groupname', 'modifieddate']
d_type =['integer', 'character varying', 'character varying', 'timestamp without time zone']

sql_query = "CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE(\n"

for column, datatype in zip(c_name, d_type):
    sql_query += f"\t\"{column}\" \"{datatype}\",\n"

sql_query += ");"

print(sql_query)
```

The `zip()` function helps deal with two (or more) iterables simultaneously without using `range()` and `len()` to create a counter.

Comment: I find this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48604563/creating-a-data-structure-from-json-using-python) But I can not do this on two lists

Comment: I'm editing a solution into my answer, for the sake of formatting.